# Install strongloop Centos 7 error

Tags: node.js, npm, strongloop, npm-install

```
[root@strongloop node_modules]# npm install -g strongloop
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
Killed ............] \ fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.n
```

When I use npm to install strongloop, It can't run, It error like above. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are no actual errors in your captured output, only non-fatal warnings. Are you killing the installation with `ctrl+c`? If it is dying on its own, do you have less than 1GB of memory on this server/workstation?

If this is a small VM on somewhere like AWS or DO with only 512mb of memory, you'll likely need to create a swap file and enable it.